# How to update data in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

i have tried to update data of my database, but there is no error
this my method

```
public function update_pj_si(request $request)
{
    $id = $request->id;
    DB::table('tbl_profil_penyedia')
        ->where('id_profil_penyedia', $id)
        ->update(array('status' => 1));
    return redirect('/verif/pj_si');
}
```

if i run this method, it run correctly and no error but the database is not updated.
how can i fix this?

Comment: For one, `(request $request)` should be `(Request $request)`.. But you say you did not get an error.. that's strange. Is that a typo?

Comment: that means the `where` condition of the query didn't yield any results to update ... the `update` call should return an integer of the number of records that were affected

Comment: May be you required this code in your model  `protected $fillable = ['status']`

Comment: yap, there is no error if i run the method, but the data is no update and i have tried to change (request $request) to (Request $request) but the result still same

Comment: @MuqsithArsyad try to `dd(DB::table('tbl_profil_penyedia')
        ->where('id_profil_penyedia', $id)
        ->update(array('status' => 1));)`, if the return is 1, means updated success, if not, means updated failed. And if it is 0

Comment: @TsaiKoga it return 0

Comment: @MuqsithArsyad  what about `dd(DB::table('tbl_profil_penyedia')->where('id_profil_penyedia', $id)->get())`, Is that empty?

Comment: @MuqsithArsyad think about what lagbox said. TsaiKoga is on the right track now I think.

Comment: could you dd() for $id?

Comment: @TsaiKoga its empty.. and now resolved.. thankyou :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$id` variable doesn't contain a value that exists in your table, `tbl_profil_penyedia`, for the field `id_profil_penyedia`. It is as simple as that.

You are trying to update a `profil_penyedia` that doesn't exist.

The `update` call returning `0`, means it didn't update any rows, which means your `where` condition didn't yield any results to be updated.

Comment: thankyou sir.. before, i have tried input tag table in tag form. so $id cant call and returning 0. after i delete tag table it works. and i want ask again sir.. can the table tag be in the form tag?